# How can I reduce the size of TTF file?

Tags: css, font-face, truetype

Am using font face method  for my website.For that am using TTF file.The problem am facing is due to the size of TTF file the site loading slowly.So suggest me how to reduce the size of TTF file.Thanks.

Comment: gzip it on the server and serve with cache-forever headers..

Comment: This might help for eternal caching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970938/ideal-http-cache-control-headers-for-different-types-of-resources

Comment: And this might help with gzipping your TTFs: http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into the amount of glyphs you are using in the font and try to reduce it to the absolute necessary ones, the [Font Squirrel kit generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator), when in Expert Mode, lets you select the symbols you want to use.

Read more at [Limit characterset of a Webfont?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732372/limit-characterset-of-a-webfont)

Comment: How can I reduce font icon by remove some icon unnecessary of group font icons?